# Template for a dynamic url to create a new Google contact?

Tags: php

I would like to create a url so a user can click a hyperlink and send some PHP variables to populate some fields to create a new Google Contact.

I have found answers on this site for creating such links to create a new Google Event and for linking to a Google Maps address, but I can't find one for Google Contacts.  I also find a lot of info about the Google Contacts API, but I don't want to use the API if I can help it.  I tried to use the API to create a Google Event but I'm not a great programmer and couldn't figure out how to configure everything with my server.

Below is the template I have been using to create a new Google Event and now I would like a similar dynamic url using PHP variables to start a new Google Contact, if that is possible.

```
"<a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=<?php echo $eventname; ?>&dates=<?= $googleformatdatetimeinspection ?>/<?= $googleformatdatetimeinspection2 ?>&details=<?= $assignmentnotes ?> <?= $statusnotes ?>&location=<?php echo $googleformattedinsuredfulladdress ?>&sf=true&output=xml&add='someemail@gmail.com'">"
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a url instead of the Google Contacts API? Helping us understand that could lead to better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the question Jason.  I am not a great programmer and the API is complicated to get configured.  I tried it a lot when I was trying to figure out how to create a new Google Event using the API.  I finally found a template for the url to create a new event with a few fields populated from PHP variables and it worked really easy so I am hoping to find a similar template for creating a new Google Contact.  I'll revise my question a bit, so thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I took a peek at the JS source of https://contacts.google.com/new, and it looks like it's extracting the following fields from the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

- `givenname`
- `familyname`
- `email` (comma-separated)
- `phone` (comma-separated)

So you can construct a URL like this, and it will pre-fill those fields:

https://contacts.google.com/new?email=jack@example.com,jack@example.net&phone=+1%20206%20555%200100,+1%20206%20555%200199&givenname=Jack&familyname=Smith

[image: cropped screenshot of a pre-filled new Google Contact form]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to do this then I have some good news and some bad news.

The good news is that you could create a URL to a PHP page with some variables.
For example:  http://mywebpage.com/createcontact.php?firstname=Bob&lastname=Smith

The bad news is that the createcontact.php will still need to hit the Google Contacts API to create the contacts record (perhaps via a cURL or similar).  i.e. Using the appropriate API key etc.

https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/?csw=1#Creating

Some words of warning:
-  You might want to consider restricting access to the URL via geoip
-  I'd recommend keeping the number of inputs fairly small to begin with
-  Don't forget to use the Google API Admin Console to restrict access to your API keys whether client side or server side to avoid them being misused/abused by others.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I know how to create a dynamic link to PHP pages if I know the url and fields.  I am looking specifically for the url and fields to Google's "Create new contact" page.